# Android Studio emulator keeps freezing, crashing, and is not responding at all

Tags: android-studio

I'm a starting Android development and have recently ran into some problems. I don't know whether it is my hardware or if it's Android Studio but the emulator keeps freezing or is not responding.

The first 2 days Android Studio was running fine. However, after that it cannot run my apps. I reinstalled Android Studio and it worked for one day, but now even if I reinstall it, it won't run any apps and even Android Studio itself would occasionally freeze and I will have to restart it.

The emulator either does this or does not even turn on:

[image: The emulator either does this or does not even turn on]

it won't even respond when I click on anything on the emulator

---

Here is a break down of what's been happening.

- Day 1: works fine.
- Day 2: Android Studio freezes multiple times when I launch the emulator. Emulator unresponsive to clicks. I uninstall Android Studio thrn install it again. After reinstallation it works 100% again with the same app
- Day 3: emulator unresponsive, freezes. Menu bottons such as rotate screen, back etc. unresponsive.
- Day 4: same as day 3. Uninstall Android, reinstall. Unresponsive.

Comment: You should just configure the ram of AVD. Kill the background services which eat ram too much. Example : Google Chrome .. etc

Comment: You never called show() on the Toasts, by the way

Comment: San ko ko sorry for my ignorance but how do configure the Ram of avd? And what does that mean?

Comment: Did you install HAXM ? Install it if you haven't done that. Windows Hyper-V has eliminated the use of HAXM (I don't have it installed yet), so check if it is installed

Comment: It works on your mobile device, good! But when you want to test for different screen sizes and densities, you'll definitely need the emulator. It's inevitable

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing this line of code `System.out.println(userinput1);` to `Log.d(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), userinput1)` because on emulator system.out.println() automatically redirects to logcat but sometimes not. 

This problem may arise due to low ram size, android studio works fine with `8GB Ram.`
Or try to config emulator properly. 
 Let me know if problem continues.

Comment: oh I completely forgot that i had that line in there. i should not even have that there

Comment: Still says my app is not responding on the emulator

Comment: I assume that in your XML file you put onCLick on the button so that it can call clickFunction method else try to attach the button to the Java file.
Putting code in the answer above.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the emulator freezing

Comment: Then while making the AVD, RAM parameter are not adjusted properly.

Comment: Would you by any chance know how  i should o abouts configuring the avd ram parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that import just specific address of class not the whole package or as bundle.
With

```
import java.util.*;
```

all classes of java.util package is imported.
The problem might be that, your hardware might be overwhelmed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anything is wrong with your code. What is your system configuration? Does other applications work on emulator work? Can you post you
post your logcat? 
PS: I know it should have been a comment. But I don't have permissions, sorry.

Comment: Day 1: everything was working 100% smoothly Day 2: android studio kept freezing so i uninstall and install it again. It then worked smoothly 100%. Day 3: emulator stops responding altogether. I uninstall again then install. Emulator still unresponsive. Day4: same as day 3. Day 5: today

Comment: I will post my logcat as soon as I get home. Thanks!

Comment: I put up some of my logcat. not sure what to show everyone

Comment: 06-18 02:08:14.909 1576-1588/system_process I/ActivityManager: Process com.example.jimmy.higherorlower (pid 10313) has died
06-18 02:08:14.909 1576-1588/system_process D/ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 10313

Answer (score 0):

## Problem and solution

Same problem, unusable for serious testing, whole system locking up regularly (Linux Mint Vera | 16GB-RAM | Nvidia GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 3GB] -- worked fine on Windows 7, exact same hardware (although hard drive config has changed slightly, might need to double-check the OS drive is connected port0 on motherboard in case of performance impact).

It's ironic that Android being Linux based, struggles to run in a Linux env xD.

---

Tried different:

- Linux APIs
- Emulator Phone Models
- Phone RAM specs, processor specs, etc
  ( All different graphics modes (both in native A-Studio emulator and using the apt install-google-emulator option for vanilla standalone (old school) version. Old school version runs better (standalone version).
- Checked all microcode updates and drivers are in order. (Using Nvidia GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 3GB]
- System is up to date (apt)

---

Found the best options:

**Performance Better: Restart Android Emulated Device with 'Cold Boot' option specified**

*or*

**Use Diff Emulator: Virtual Machine Manager / Virsh (KVM-QEMU)**

*or*

**Use Physical Device: With Android 11+ you can wifi pair.**

---

With devices APIs lower than 11, there is no Wi-Fi pair feature so I found solution was to install termux on the handset I wanted to use for app testing, which gave me a standardish shell with apt pkg manager -- then I could install sshd and connect to dev-PC with portforward i.e

**$ SSH from Phone to PC with: ssh -R 4444:127.0.0.1:5555 ubuntu@192.168.1.20**

**$ SSH from PC to Phone with: ssh -L 4444:127.0.0.1:5555 ubuntu@192.168.1.20**

(The exact command may vary, written from memory as quick guide to get you moving right direction thought ports are correct, syntax may need adjusting and of course, the username@hostIP needs setting to your you-login@your-computers--LAN-IP).

---

Once an SSH connection has been established, which you can check using something like

```
$ ss -tulpan | grep 4444
or
$ netstat -tulpan | grep 4444
```

Once confirmed established, you need to fire up adb to connect to the now available Android adb service that we forwarded from the handset into the dev-PC by running the command (also make sure you have USB debugging enabled  on the handset before doing this);

On dev-PC run;

```
$ adb connect 127.0.0.1:4444
```

It should say 'CONNECTED'.

Then to double check, run:

```
$ adb devices
```

Emulator should show up in Android Studio  Device Manager. Give it a few minutes and Android Studio will pick it up!

I can't remember the specific reason I needed to do it this way as opposed to just connecting with a USB cable. I think I was doing some mad routed setup. But there we have it!

I found using a physical device to be the ultimate performance solution but is of course a bulky arrangement.

### Update

Increasing memory available to Android Studio and the VM made big difference (I have 16gb RAM).

```
Android Studio > Help > Change Memory Settings (2048 -> 4096)
Android Studio > Help > Edit Custom VM Options > add/replace-->
                                   (-Xmx4096m
                                   (-Xmx4096m
```

(Then finally added extra config to Gradle script to allow extra memory but I don't think that would have an impact on the slow running issue as was entire emulator crumbling not just the app.)

In gradle.properties, replace `order.gradle.jvmargs....` (with)
`org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`

Finally, restart Android / Emulator and remember to do a COLD BOOT on your emulator device.

Comment: Please remove unnecessary formatting and all text not related to the answer.

Comment: I would normally have downvoted this due to the amount of work it needed to make it readable. However, I concede that it does seem to be helpful, so it escapes digital admonishment for now. But, for the love of all that is holy, please make an effort with your formatting and presentation. Markdown is dead easy to learn, and it makes all the difference for future readers.

Comment: Someone will benefit from the answer, which is the most important thing, but yes Viktor has half a point and halfer has a full point.

Viktor, remove all text not related to the answer.

;)